# IGB Driver Massive packet loss on Debian Linux 6.0

Tags: debian, linux-device-driver, intel, drivers

I am running Debian Linux 6.0 (2.6.32-5-amd64).
My network NICS are Intel 82580 Gigabit running with the IGB network driver version 3.3.6 (firmware version 3.2-9).

I tested the performance and I noticed massive packet drops.

My test is simple: 
tcpreplay a file to the IGB interface and run tcpdump on the other side to verify that all packets have arrived.

Even with small throughput I experience many drops.

I switched ports to an old e1000e driver, and everything worked like a charm.

I tried doing the following and i got the same results:

Downgraded the driver version
 installed the sorceforce igb driver 
 installed PF_RING with igb support
 Played with snaplen, and buffering
 I upgraded the kernel version to the latest 3.2.5 from kernel.org

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank You

Comment: +1 for good question, but voted for close because it needs to go over to Serverfault.com